# Error starting mod_wsgi

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi

When I run the start-server command on mod_wsgi-experess, I get this output:

```
Server URL      : http://localhost:8000/
Server Root     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0
Server Conf     : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf
Error Log       : /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/error_log
httpd: Syntax error on line 2 of /tmp/mod_wsgi-localhost:8000:0/httpd.conf: module version_module is built-in and can't be loaded
```

The line 2 in the httpd.conf in the tmp folder that it is referring to says the following. It was automatically created by mod_wsgi:

```
LoadModule version_module '/usr/local/apache/modules/mod_version.so'
```

I am running Apache 2.2.21 on CentOS 5.10.

I am stumped. Any ideas how to get over this obstacle?

I should mention that this is a [cross-post of a StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24110683/error-starting-mod-wsgi), after I realized that SO was probably not the best place to ask it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have moved it here, can you try:

```
pip install -U https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/archive/develop.zip
```

This has a fix which I hope will deal with the case where modules are statically compiled into Apache.

As I said before, having lots of modules statically compiled into Apache can be a bit silly as it limits your ability to reduce memory usage of Apache. I really question the choice by CentOS to statically link the modules rather than rely on dynamically loading them.

Comment: Hey Graham, indeed I can! Glad you followed this. I will delete the SO post. I have been keeping an eye on mod_wsgi on GitHub and I actually just noticed your commit relating to this issue. I was surprised! But pleasantly pleased. Anyway, I'm getting a new error message which I'm sure you would like to know: http://pastebin.com/vdN55qgk It sounds like it might be happy if I run it not as root? Update: just tried it as another user. Got this: /usr/sbin/httpd: line 63: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted.

Comment: If running as root, you would need to specify the ``--user`` and ``--group`` options and set them to whatever the Apache user is on the system, or some other user that you want your Python web application to run as. Normally a different approach would be used to get things setup if eventually intend running mod_wsgi express as root which I haven't described anywhere yet. This is where the mod_wsgi mailing list becomes a better place to discuss things.

Comment: The bigger problem is that on CentOS they appear to have replaced the original Apache executable with a shell script which does extra things which screws things up. You would need to find where the original Apache executable is and use the option ``--httpd-executable`` to specify the location of it.

Comment: So do you think I should not be running it as root anyway? I'm open to suggestion, as this is all pretty new territory for me. And if I use --httpd-executable, do I still need to specify the user and group as you mentioned above?

Comment: If you intend it to be available on port 80 as would normally be used by public facing web sites, you have no choice but to start it as root. If starting as root, whether or not you have to override which httpd executable is used, you would have to specify the user and group. Can you at least try and work out from the httpd shell script on CentOS what the real Apache executable binary is as I will update documentation with details of that issue and how to start up as root.

Comment: Yeah Graham, I've been poking around at that. It looks like httpd lives in /usr/sbin/  When I run it as root, specifying the user, it gets to the point where I was getting the error messages and then it seems to hang. I can't seem to stop the script at that point, nor does the server seem to be actually active. It is outputting an error log though: http://pastebin.com/6jQzb4hx

Comment: At that point I would suggest that SELinux may be enabled on your system and is screwing things up. Try temporarily disabling any SELinux extensions and see if that helps. For details on how to do that see http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/disable_selinux.html

Comment: I have updated README at https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi with information on non standard Apache installations and running as root.